# Find last not NULL value for each column in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a table with columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. In each row, only one of these values is not null. I'd like to find the latest value for `col1`, `col2` and `col3` (obviously from three separate rows), where these are not `NULL`.

Here is a schema:

- `col1` - `INT`
- `col2` - `INT`
- `col3` - `INT`
- `timestamp` - `DATETIME`

Assume I have this data:

```
+------+------+------+------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |    timestamp     |
+------+------+------+------------------+
| 1    | NULL | NULL | 15/09/2016 10:55 |
| NULL | 2    | NULL | 15/09/2016 10:56 |
| NULL | NULL | 3    | 15/09/2016 10:57 |
| 4    | NULL | NULL | 15/09/2016 10:58 |
+------+------+------+------------------+
```

I want the following results:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    4 |    2 |    3 |
+------+------+------+
```

How can I write a query to do this?

Comment: latest relative to what?

Comment: @vkp you can assume that it goes by a `timestamp` column in descending order.

Comment: can you provide with sample input and output...

Comment: @SOaddict yes, sorry.

Comment: Already given. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  (select col1 from tbl where col1 is not null order by timestamp desc limit 1) as col1,
  (select col2 from tbl where col2 is not null order by timestamp desc limit 1) as col2,
  (select col3 from tbl where col3 is not null order by timestamp desc limit 1) as col3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column, such as `timestamp` that specifies the ordering, then you can get the last id for each using:

```
select max(case when col1 is not null then timestamp end) as ts1,
       max(case when col2 is not null then timestamp end) as ts2,
       max(case when col3 is not null then timestamp end) as ts3
from t;
```

You can then get the rows you want using a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select max(case when col1 is not null then timestamp end) as ts1,
             max(case when col2 is not null then timestamp end) as ts2,
             max(case when col3 is not null then timestamp end) as ts3
      from t
     ) tt
     on t.timestamp in (ts1, ts2, ts3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
select @a:=null, @b:=null, @c:=null;
select A,B,C from (
    select @a:=coalesce(A,@a) as A, @b:=coalesce(B,@b) as B, @c:=coalesce(C,@) as C time
    from yourtable
    order by time asc
) as y order by time desc limit 1;
```

**Updated The Post:**

```
  SELECT DISTINCT (
  SELECT col1
  FROM demo
  WHERE IFNULL(col1, 0) != 0 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) col1, (
  SELECT col2
  FROM demo
  WHERE IFNULL(col2, 0) != 0 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) col2, (
  SELECT col3
  FROM demo
  WHERE IFNULL(col3, 0) != 0 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) col3
FROM demo
```

Table structure:

```
 col1    col2    col3  timestamp
  1       2        8   2016-09-02 10:00:00
  0       4        10  2016-09-04 12:00:00
```

Returns:

```
 col1    col2    col3 
   1       4      10
```

Comment: your query isn't working for me... can you please rework it for `col1`, `col2` and `col3`?

Comment: Give a try changing the columns according to yours. No worries if it doesn't work. I'll get on this.

Comment: I guess, I am too late to update the post. But you can check.